# Spring Authorization Server with custom login

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I'm trying the new spring framework

```
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
```

I got the POC working perfectly from baeldung, but when I try go farther than the default config, I didn't managed to get things working.

I tried to configure a custom login page , with a custom path for POSTing user information, the login page is well displayed, but after POSTing the form (username/passwrod) I'm getting a 404 (NOT_FOUND)

Here is my config:

```
@Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
// Authorization server Oauth2 default config commented
//        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
//Extracted from Oauth2 default config
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity> authorizationServerConfigurer = new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer();
        RequestMatcher endpointsMatcher = authorizationServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher();
        http      
//Here is my custom form / post login config

                .antMatcher("/**")
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/home")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/mydomain/login")
                .usernameParameter("identifier")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider)
            .requestMatcher(endpointsMatcher)
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/js/**","/assets/**", "/css/**","/home**", "/mydomain/**").permitAll()
                .and()
//Extracted from Oauth2 default config``
                .authorizeRequests((authorizeRequests) -> {
            ((ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl)authorizeRequests.anyRequest()).authenticated();
        })

                .csrf((csrf) -> {
            csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(new RequestMatcher[]{endpointsMatcher});
        })
                .apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);
        return  http.build();
```

thanks for help!
regards

Comment: Do you have a Controller to handle the loginProcessingUrl "/mydomain/login"?

Comment: No, this must trigger Spring Auth automtically and post user/password sent by form to "/mydomain/login" instead of "login (defautl)". No controller mapping needed for spring auth. Anyway, I found my way to resolve this by separating the definition of securtiy for the "login form" and "Oauth2" security config in two distinct Bean & configuration classes. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @Fozix I am getting the same issue, could you post your solution as a valid response

Answer (score 1):

Need to implement Controller like this:

```java
@GetMapping("/login")
    public String oauth2LoginPage(Model model,
                              @CurrentSecurityContext(expression = "authentication") Authentication authentication,
                              @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.server.login.captcha.enabled:true}") boolean enableCaptchaLogin,
                              @RequestAttribute(name = "org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken", required = false) CsrfToken csrfToken) {

        if (!(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)){
            return "redirect:/";
        }
        if (csrfToken != null) {
            model.addAttribute("_csrfToken", csrfToken);
        }
        SystemSettings systemSettings = new SystemSettings();
        model.addAttribute("enableCaptchaLogin",enableCaptchaLogin);
        model.addAttribute("systemSettings", systemSettings);
        return "oauth2_login";
    }
```

There are a few key points about the default HTML form:

- The form should perform a post to /login
- The form will need to include a CSRF Token which is automatically
  included by Thymeleaf.
- The form should specify the username in a parameter named username
- The form should specify the password in a parameter named password

  If the HTTP parameter error is found, it indicates the user failed to
  provide a valid username / password

  If the HTTP parameter logout is found, it indicates the user has
  logged out successfully

Reference link：https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html